# Legend issues when coordinates are missing

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I encountered a small issue when I wanted to make plots of my data. Basically, I am working on 10 different objects, which have several properties. So I have a csv file, with 10 rows and a lot of columns representing each object property. Each row have some "blanks", meaning that we don't know the property value for this object. This is represented in the following MWE by 4 objects A,B,C and D which have properties x,y,z. We know x, y and z for A and D, only x and z for B and x and y for C.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Label,x,y,z
A,1,5,9
B,4,,7
C,6,5,
D,7,3,4
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}
 \tikzset{every mark/.append style={scale=3}}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycolorlist}{%
mark=10-pointed star,only marks,point meta=explicit symbolic,blue,every mark/.append style={fill=blue!80!black}\\%
mark=diamond*,only marks,point meta=explicit symbolic,red,every mark/.append style={fill=red!80!black}\\%
mark=square*,only marks,point meta=explicit symbolic,brown!60!black,every mark/.append style={fill=brown!80!black}\\%
mark=pentagon*,only marks,point meta=explicit symbolic,black,every mark/.append style={solid,fill=black}\\%
}
\hspace*{-4cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\xx}{x};
\newcommand{\yy}{y};
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size= 2 by 1,group name=myplot,horizontal sep=2.5cm,vertical sep = 3.5cm},cycle list name=mycolorlist,legend style={at={(1.,0.5)},anchor=west}]
    \nextgroupplot[ylabel = {y},xlabel={x}]
\addplot+[discard if not={Label}{A},unbounded coords=discard]table[meta=Label,y=\yy,x=\xx,col sep=comma] {data.csv};\addlegendentry{A}
\addplot+[discard if not={Label}{B},unbounded coords=discard]table[meta=Label,y=\yy,x=\xx,col sep=comma] {data.csv};\addlegendentry{B}
\addplot+[ discard if not={Label}{C},unbounded coords=discard]table[meta=Label,y=\yy,x=\xx,col sep=comma] {data.csv};\addlegendentry{C}
\addplot+[ discard if not={Label}{D},unbounded coords=discard]table[meta=Label,y=\yy,x=\xx,col sep=comma] {data.csv};\addlegendentry{D}
\nextgroupplot[ylabel = {z},xlabel={x}]
\renewcommand{\yy}{z}
\addplot+[discard if not={Label}{A},unbounded coords=discard]table[meta=Label,y=\yy,x=\xx,col sep=comma] {data.csv};\addlegendentry{A}
\addplot+[discard if not={Label}{B},unbounded coords=discard]table[meta=Label,y=\yy,x=\xx,col sep=comma] {data.csv};\addlegendentry{B}
\addplot+[ discard if not={Label}{C},unbounded coords=discard]table[meta=Label,y=\yy,x=\xx,col sep=comma] {data.csv};\addlegendentry{C}
\addplot+[ discard if not={Label}{D},unbounded coords=discard]table[meta=Label,y=\yy,x=\xx,col sep=comma] {data.csv};\addlegendentry{D}
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives me the following plots:
[image]

On the left plot, legend is false, the brown square is in fact the object C and the black pentagon the object D (B has no value for y). On the right plot, C shouldn't appear as it does not have any value for the z property.

So I know basically I could take each property individually and plot only the good objects, but I have a lot of different properties to plot and it would take me huge amount of time to do so.

I would be really happy if someone has a solution :)

Thanks

Comment: This is quite strange, I tried it again in a local and online tex compiler and It is running. What kind of errors you get?

I'll try your solution, thanks for the lead

Comment: I found the problem:  I already had a "data.csv" file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a reather heavy handed solution, but it works.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableset{col sep=comma,string type}
\pgfplotstableread{
Label,x,y,z
A,1,5,9
B,4,,7
C,6,5,
D,7,3,4
}\Table
%\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns/Label/.style={string type}]{\Table}% for debugging
\pgfplotsset{
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}
 \tikzset{every mark/.append style={scale=3}}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycolorlist}{%
mark=10-pointed star,only marks,point meta=explicit symbolic,blue,every mark/.append style={fill=blue!80!black}\\%
mark=diamond*,only marks,point meta=explicit symbolic,red,every mark/.append style={fill=red!80!black}\\%
mark=square*,only marks,point meta=explicit symbolic,brown!60!black,every mark/.append style={fill=brown!80!black}\\%
mark=pentagon*,only marks,point meta=explicit symbolic,black,every mark/.append style={solid,fill=black}\\%
}
\hspace*{-4cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\xx}{x};
\newcommand{\yy}{y};
%\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\Table}
%\let\rows=\pgfplotsretval
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size= 2 by 1,group name=myplot,horizontal sep=2.5cm,vertical sep = 3.5cm},cycle list name=mycolorlist,legend style={at={(1.,0.5)},anchor=west}]
    \nextgroupplot[ylabel = {y},xlabel={x}]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,1,2,3}{
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Label}\of{\Table}
      \let\mark=\pgfplotsretval
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{\xx}\of{\Table}
      \let\x=\pgfplotsretval
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{\yy}\of{\Table}
      \let\y=\pgfplotsretval
      \ifx\empty\x\else
        \ifx\empty\y\else
          \addplot+[only marks] coordinates {(\x,\y)};
          \addlegendentryexpanded{\mark}
     \fi\fi}
\nextgroupplot[ylabel = {z},xlabel={x}]
\renewcommand{\yy}{z}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,1,2,3}{
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Label}\of{\Table}
      \let\mark=\pgfplotsretval
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{\xx}\of{\Table}
      \let\x=\pgfplotsretval
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{\yy}\of{\Table}
      \let\y=\pgfplotsretval
      \ifx\empty\x\else
        \ifx\empty\y\else
          \addplot+[only marks] coordinates {(\x,\y)};
          \addlegendentryexpanded{\mark}
     \fi\fi}
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]